# Is it a bad idea to swap PyCuda DeviceAllocation objects?

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda

Let's say we allocated the same amount of memory on the device using two calls like so:

```
pointerA = cuda_driver.mem_alloc(myArray.nbytes)
pointerB = cuda_driver.mem_alloc(myArray.nbytes)
```

Then we copy the same data onto the device for both DeviceAllocation objects.

```
cuda_driver.memcpy_htod(pointerA, myArray)
cuda_driver.memcpy_htod(pointerB, myArray)
```

Is it a bad idea to then swap the two DeviceAllocation objects? For example they could be swapped like this:

```
tempPointer = pointerA
pointerA = pointerB
pointerB = tempPointer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't a bad idea, quite the opposite. Pointer object exchange in PyCUDA is fully supported and is generally the right thing to do.

In general, most device to device copies in CUDA code are unnecessary and could be replace by pointer exchange. About the only time that doesn't work is when the device to device transfer only copies part of the source memory to the destination memory (or vice versa).